# cannot get Spamassassin to run on Centos 6

Tags: centos6, spamassassin

I've installed SpamAssassin twice, once using yum install spamassassin and once downloading the source from cpan.

SpamAssassin, itself runs and reports itself as v3.4.1 running on Perl 5.22.0 but whenver I run it as a daemon using 'service spamassassin start' spamd fails with the following errors:-

```
# service spamassassin start
Starting spamd: Can't use 'defined(%hash)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin/Dns.pm line 757.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin/Message/Metadata/Received.pm line 49.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin/Message/Metadata/Received.pm line 49.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin/Message/Metadata.pm line 58.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin/Message/Metadata.pm line 58.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin/Message.pm line 51.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin/Message.pm line 51.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin.pm line 75.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Mail/SpamAssassin.pm line 75.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/spamd line 85.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/spamd line 85.
                                                       [FAILED]
```

I have my suspicions that SA and its modules have been installed in a dfferent set of perl include directories as the perl v5.22.0 version gets its modules from /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.00 amongst other directories but they all have 5.22.0 in them.

I've tried re-installing Mail::SpamAssassin using cpan but it keeps on just telling me that I have the most up-to-date version.  I've also tried installing it from cpan.org source (which installs) but it does not install any dependencies and I don't know what is needed.

I've tried doing a cpan fforce install of Mail::SpamAssassin but it make no difference.

Spamd is run using perl v5.22.0 so should (I would have thought) access the 5.22.0 include directories.

I'm now completely stuck.

1. How can I get SpamAssassin to run in conjunction with Postfix and Dovecot so as to weed out the welter of spam that I get.
2. If it proves impossible to get SpamAssassin running, is there an alternative?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Odd, https://api.metacpan.org/source/KMCGRAIL/Mail-SpamAssassin-3.4.1/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Dns.pm is only 739 lines long, while your error message indicates 757. Also, perl 5.22 is not typical for Centos 6; there is probably some confusion going on as to what version got installed where and conflicts resulting from such.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that has actually pointed me to the solution.  See answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that spamd needed to run under perl 5.10.1, the originally installed version on this server.  So, instead of having a shebang of:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T -w
```

it just needed

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.10.1 -T -w
```

Partly the clue was in the error message (reading the wrong include files) and mainly it was down to thrig's comment - thanks

Comment: You should mark your answer as accepted -- you can do that even though you answered your own question. It will help keep things tidy.